# What is being integrated here concerning fundamental matrices in ODEs?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

This is a passage from Ferdinand verhult's ``Nonlinear Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems'' (Theorem 6.2):

Consider the differential equation
$$
\dot{x}=Ax+B(t)x,
$$
$A$ $n\times n$ real matrix, $B(t)$ real continuous, defined for $t\geq t_0$.

Let $\Phi(x)$ be the fundamental matrix of $\dot{x}=Ax$, which can be written as
$$
\Phi(t)=\exp(A(t-t_0)).
$$

Substituting $x=\Phi(t)z$ in the ODE yields

$$
\dot{z}=\Phi^{-1}(t) B(t) \Phi(t).
$$

The author then says "Integration of this expression and multiplication with $\Phi(t)$ produces for the solutions of the ODE the integral equation:"

$$
x(t)=\Phi(t) x_0 +\int_{t_0}^t \Phi(t-\tau+t_0)B(\tau)x(\tau) d\tau
$$

Here it's used the fact that $\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(\tau)=\Phi(t-\tau+t_0)$.

I can't seem to understand how it is being integrated here. Would someone care to explain? I seem to be missing something really simple here.

I know this is from variation of constants and that there are some other formulations for the expression of the solutions but I really need the integration step in here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some typo: the substitution should be $x=\Phi(t)z$, and we have
$$
\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(\tau)=\Phi(t-\tau+t_0).
$$
From the equation for $z$ after the substitution,
$$
\dot{z}=\Phi^{-1}(t)B\Phi(t)z,
$$
We have
$$
\dot{z}=\Phi^{-1}(t)B x(t).
$$

Replace $t$ by $\tau$ and integrate from $t_0$ to $t$ gives
$$
z(t)=z(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^t \Phi^{-1}(\tau)B x(\tau) d\tau.
$$
Multiply $\Phi(t)$ on the left, then
$$
x(t)=x(t_0)+\Phi(t)\int_{t_0}^t \Phi^{-1}(\tau)B x(\tau) d\tau.
$$
This is the result.

Comment: Fixed the typo.